# How do I increase the size of the images in a 'template_icon_view'?

Tags: python, scripting

Anybody know if it's possible to change the thumbnail size? The red is easy by doing `col.template_icon_view(brush, "items", show_labels=True, scale=8)` ,but I'm trying to figure out the green.

[image]

Found `icon_size` and `image_size` ,but can't get anything to happen with those.

https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.ImagePreview.html#bpy.types.ImagePreview

```
def preview_items(self, context):        
    enum_items = []
    # Valid file extensions   
    extensions = ('.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png')
    
    if context is None:        
        return enum_items
        
    directory = "C:\\Users\User Name\Desktop\thumbnails\\"  
          
    pcoll = preview_thumbnails_collections["main"]

    if directory == pcoll.my_previews_dir:
        return pcoll.my_previews
                        
    if directory and os.path.exists(directory):
        image_paths = []
                                
        for fn in os.listdir(directory):
            if fn.endswith(extensions):
                image_paths.append(fn)

        for i, name in enumerate(image_paths):
            filepath = os.path.join(directory, name)
         
            icon = pcoll.get(name)
                       
            if not icon:
                thumb = pcoll.load(name, filepath, 'IMAGE')
                
#>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Neither does anything, just makes thumbnails not show ????
                thumb.image_size = (350, 350)
                thumb.icon_size = (350, 350)                
#>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 
                                                                                                                                               
            else:
                thumb = pcoll[name]
                                      
            enum_items.append((name, name, name, thumb.icon_id, i))
                          
    pcoll.my_previews = enum_items
    pcoll.my_previews_dir = directory
        
    return pcoll.my_previews
```

OK, finally figured this out by looking at source code. You use `scale_popup=8` for the green part and `scale=8` for the red part.